# Trouble with "Type 'Error?' has no member 'localizedDescription'"

Tags: ios, swift

```
@IBAction func signUpButton_TouchUpInside(_ sender: Any) {

    if !isValidEmailAddress(emailAddressString: emailTextField.text!) {
        self.signUpErrorLabel.text = "Please enter a valid email address."
    }

    Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: emailTextField.text!, password: passwordTextField.text! , completion: {
        (user: User?, error: Error?) in
        let err = NSError()
        if Error.self != nil {
            self.signUpErrorLabel.isHidden = false
            if Error?.localizedDescription == "This email is already in use." {
                self.signUpErrorLabel.text = "That email is already in use."
            }


        }
        else {
            self.signUpErrorLabel.isHidden = true
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "welcomeSegue", sender: nil)

            let uid = user?.uid
            let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference(forURL: Config.STORAGE_ROOF_REF).child("Profile Image").child(uid!)

            if let profileImg = self.selectedImage, let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(profileImg, 0.1) {
                storageRef.putData(imageData, metadata: nil, completion: {
                    (metadata, error) in
                    if error != nil {
                    }
                    let profileImageUrl = metadata?.downloadURL()?.absoluteString
                    self.setUserInformation(email: self.emailTextField.text!, uid: uid!,profileImgUrl: profileImageUrl! )
                })

            }
            self.setUserInformation(email: self.emailTextField.text!, uid: uid!, profileImgUrl: " ")
        }
    })
}
```

Here is my code above.  When I try to run this it gives me an error:

> Type 'Error?' has no member 'localizedDescription'".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `error` (the variable that was passed to the closure), not `Error` (a type):

```
Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: emailTextField.text!, password: passwordTextField.text! , completion: { user, error in
    if let error = error {
        self.signUpErrorLabel.isHidden = false
        if error.localizedDescription == "This email is already in use." {
            self.signUpErrorLabel.text = "That email is already in use."
        }
        return
    }
    ...
}
```